# How to install nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I'm new to python, I'm using Windows 10 and I basically have to use nltk for my project, but this error massage appears to me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>   
  import nltk 
ImportError: No module named 'nltk'
```

Comment: `sudo pip install -U nltk`

Comment: it doesn't work with me, can you show me all the steps from the beginning, and what python version do you use?

Comment: on windows `py -m pip install ntlk` or `python -m pip install ntlk` try both. You input the commands into command prompt (cmd)

Comment: @EsraaAli What does it do instead of working?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9